# PowerShell or CMD - Find and Increment alphabet letter of files (revision management)

Tags: powershell, cmd, increment, revision, alphabet

I need some help to automate rename files in a current directory.
The following files that can exits in the directory is for example:

AAA111**A**.txt

AAA111**A**.pdf

AAA111**A**.jpg

BBB222**B**.jpg

BBB222**B**.pdf

Where the bold letter stand for the revision of the file.
What I want is a PowerShell or batch file where it automatically looks what revision letter it is and then increment that revision letter with the next in the alphabet for all files.

*Example:*

AAA111**A**.txt -> AAA111**B**.txt

BBB222**B**.pdf -> BBB222**C**.pdf

etc

The letters and numbers before the revision letter and the extension of the file can vary, so used as a wildcard? It is also possible that the file is named like: AAA111**A**-01.pdf or AAA111**A**-blabla.pdf

Hopefully someone can make my life easier for this noobie :).

Thank you in advance!

Comment: yeah what happens when the revision letter is `Z` ? since the naming convention of the files can vary, what is the pattern to find that specific letter ? did you give a try at solving the problem yourself ?

Comment: That much high revision letter won't happen. Otherwise with an error will do, or repeat back to `A`. To more clear the naming can vary but not random. `*A-01.txt`,`*A-02.txt` etc and `A-old.txt`. The extension can vary in 5 different extenstions. I forgot to mention that in the directory every file has the same revision letter. So there is no mix up with the letters.  I was trying to begin with the `Get-ChildItem *.txt | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace 'A.txt','B.txt'}` command, but then I need to do it for every letter in the alphabet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building off of Abraham's answer, because the use of a scriptblock with parameter to evaluate the replacement is great and not something I knew about before today. I'd just setup a hashtable ahead of time for the replacement letter(s). I'd replace `z` with `aa` to avoid conflicts, assuming that doesn't break the naming convention.

```
$Letters=[hashtable]::new() #unconventional hashtable creation to create a hashtable with case sensitive keys
65..122|?{$_ -lt 90 -or $_ -gt 96}| #this gets up A through Z and a through z, skipping the other characters between the sets
    ForEach-Object{$Letters.add([string][char]$_, [string][char]($_+1))}
$Letters.'Z'='AA' #manually set rollover case
$Letters.'z'='aa' #manually set rollover case
```

Once you get that setup you can basically do what Abraham suggested, just referencing the hashtable to get the replacement string.

```
Get-ChildItem C:\Path\To\Files*.txt|
    Rename-item -NewName {
        [regex]::replace($_.Name, '(?<=^[a-zA-Z0-9]+)([a-zA-Z])(?=\W)',{param($old)$Letters[$old.value]})
        }
```

This has the same failing that Abraham's answer does in that it does not check for file name availability before trying to rename a file. It does solve the case where a file's revision is at `Z` though. My regex is also a little more flexible for cases where a file is named something like 'AAAA111C-glarb.txt' and will correctly increment it to 'AAAA111D-glarb.txt'.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not on PowerShell core (*like me*), you can use the [`Replace()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace?view=net-7.0) static method on the `[regex]` class for a more advanced replacement. This gives us some flexibility to change the matched *character* to it's corresponding *integer* where we could add `1` to it, then change it back to its equivalent letter:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path '.\MyPath' | 
    Rename-Item -NewName {
        [regex]::Replace($_.BaseName,
            '[A-Z]$', {
                Param($match)
                $letter_int = [int][char]$match.Value + 1
                [char]$letter_int
            }
        ) + $_.Extension
    } -WhatIf
```

This doesn't account for other issues that you may encounter such as duplicate file names, or as Santiago mentioned in the comments, the logic that would be needed if the letter reaches the end of the alphabet.

---

*Remove the `-WhatIf` safety common parameter when you've dictated that is the result you're after.*

Comment: Thank you! This looks good. Only one thing is that the all letters in de Basename are changed. 
Would like that only the revision letter is changed. 
The last letter before the extension and/or last letter before the character `-` are possible.

What if output is now:
`AAA111A.txt` ->`BBB111B.txt`
`BBB111A.txt` -> `CCC111B.txt`

Tried with `$_.BaseName[-1]` and playing with `$_.BaseName.Substring`, but not really working out.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: @Martijn, my apologies, I didn't realize you wanted the **last** letter changed. I've update my answer to reflect that.